# Append d3.gantt chart to a selected div

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I create a D3 Gantt chart.

with morte or less this code:

```
var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus)    
gantt(tasks)
```

this automatically creates a new svg called chart.

I want to add it to my existing div

```
<div id ="resultContainer">
</div>
```

I did some research in thesource code over at github (https://github.com/dk8996/Gantt-Chart/blob/master/gantt-chart-d3.js quite in the end) and found the possibility to set a selector like

```
d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus).selector('#resultContainer')
```

But that crashes.
Does anybody know how to add it to an existing div?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a mistake from the author of that library.

At the end of the code he wrote this:

```
gantt.selector = function(value) {
if (!arguments.length)
    return selector;
selector = value;
return gantt;
};
```

Which, as you pointed out, could allow the user to set the selector.

However, at the beginning of the code, he wrote...

```
var selector = 'body';
```

... which renders the previous function useless. It always appends to the `<body>`.

**Solution**: Download the library and create your own version, changing...

```
var selector = 'body';
```

... for just:

```
var selector;
```

With that change you can pass your selection using `selector()`.

Here is a demo, I'm using a bl.locks from the same author of the library. I copied the library and changed the mentioned variable. In the HTML, I created a div with a class `.foo` before a paragraph with a *lorem ipsum*. Then, I selected the div with:

```
var gantt = d3.gantt().selector(".foo").taskTypes(taskNames).etc...
```

You can see (inspecting the page) that the chart is appended to the div, not to the body: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/84385e7c6ac859ad24feb3662e46e3fd/

Actually, you don't even need to inspect the page: if it was appended to the body the *lorem ipsum* would be above the chart, not below, as it is.